# git trying to push non existent file

Tags: git, github, push

Im trying the following command:

```
$ git push --set-upstream origin patch-cleanfiles
Enumerating objects: 336, done.
Counting objects: 100% (336/336), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (326/326), done.
Writing objects: 100% (336/336), 280.48 MiB | 613.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 336 (delta 146), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (146/146), done.
remote: error: Trace: 843cbb54d34aef5ff3a234efb921f178f5b03980de1c05808c14f12bdf6470c0
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File doc/Initial Call/Thomas,Isaias, Joe- -overview.mp4 is 262.90 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
To https://github.com/RaptorX/Paragrafen.app.git
 ! [remote rejected] patch-cleanfiles -> patch-cleanfiles (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/RaptorX/Paragrafen.app.git'
```

The funny thing is that i do not have a folder named "doc" in my project, so the whole file doesnt exist and trying to remove it from the working tree is not working at all:

```
$ git rm -r --cached doc/*
fatal: pathspec 'doc/*' did not match any files

$ git rm -r --cached doc/*.mp4
fatal: pathspec 'doc/*.mp4' did not match any files

$ git rm -r --cached doc/Initial\ Call/*.mp4
fatal: pathspec 'doc/Initial Call/*.mp4' did not match any files

$ git rm -r --cached doc/Initial\ Call/*
fatal: pathspec 'doc/Initial Call/*' did not match any files

$ git rm -rf --cached *.mp4
fatal: pathspec '*.mp4' did not match any files
```

This is what git is currently tracking:

```
$ git ls-tree --full-tree --name-only -r HEAD
.gitignore
.gitmodules
License.txt
README.md
Sample Texts/Demo.docx
Sample Texts/Really long sample 2.docx
Sample Texts/Sample.txt
Sample Texts/Sample_A_1_before.docx
Sample Texts/Sample_A_2_after.docx
src/Paragrafen-App.ahk
src/lib/ActiveScript.ahk
src/lib/ScriptObject
src/lib/gui/badge.ahk
src/lib/law_linker.js
src/res/Logo.png
src/res/Splash.png
src/res/app.ico
```

any pointers as to how I can start troubleshooting this particular issue?

Comment: It looks like a corrupt git index to me.

Comment: already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/24114760/11430151

Comment: @HassanElshazlyEida I think that answer is unrelated because as you can see my first command is setting up a new upstream branch. the remote repository is empty.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Thats my guess but im not sure where to start troubleshooting. Ill check on how to fix a corrupt index and start from there.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution to the problem.

Even though the file was not in the index there was history of it being committed and that was the issue when trying to push it.

After reading these instructions posted [here](https://support-acquia.force.com/s/article/360004334093-Removing-large-files-from-Git-without-losing-history) I was able to fix it with this command:

```
$ git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch ./doc/*.mp4' --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

beware that the filter-branch command is a bit complex and you might create other problems.

After running that command I was able to remove all unwanted files from the database but kept the commit history (as far as I understand).